# Is there a way to have a static public IP on my Cloud Build worker?

Tags: google-cloud-build

I have a Postgres instance on Azure exposed to the internet. In order to access it, I'd need the public IP of my Cloud Build worker to be whitelisted.

From my understanding, the public IP of Cloud Build workers by default are not static, which making accessing the Postgres impossible from Cloud Build. Is there a way to create custom pools from custom worker images?

I have also checked private pools, but it seems I can only define them in terms of VPC. Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it's not possible to have a static public IP with Cloud Build. To solve your issue, I think about 2 solutions:

- Create a Cloud Run or a Cloud Functions which proxy the connection (I don't know what you do exactly with your database, but you can send command/query to your serverless service, it executes them, and send back the result). Those serverless services can have a static outgoing public IP (via Cloud NAT)
- User private pool and set up a VPN between your VPC and the Azure tenant. And reach the database on the private IP.